# subprocess.CalledProcessError returned non-zero exit status 1

Tags: android, python, ubuntu, kivy

while running kivy, I am getting this error. I have already ant installed.

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ant', 'debug']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

can anyone tell me why this error comes? due to python or ant or any thing else?

Comment: It seems that it's the usage of the command you issued rather than the absence of `ant` in your OS that causes the problem. So check the command you issued in subprocess.

Comment: This is a fairly generic error. Please post a full log (you can obtain it by setting log_level to 2 in your buildozer.spec), as well as your buildozer.spec itself.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error, but **the real error** was slightly above this:

```py
Buildfile: /Users/rallen/Documents/Devel/python/kivy/python-for-android/dist/default/build.xml

BUILD FAILED
/Users/rallen/Documents/Devel/python/kivy/python-for-android/dist/default/build.xml:6: **Source resource does not exist: /Users/rallen/Documents/Devel/python/kivy/python-for-android/dist/default/project.properties**

Total time: 0 seconds
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./build.py", line 412, in <module>
    make_package(args)
  File "./build.py", line 336, in make_package
    subprocess.check_call([ANT, arg])
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 511, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ant', 'debug']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Googling a bit, I found

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kivy-users/igYampuxxCU

which said to just create `dist/default/project.properties` and put

```
target=android-14
```

in that file. I actually used `android-19`, but that has gotten me past this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to install 32 bit libraries.
For example, I needed to install `lib32-glibc`,`lib32-libstdc++5` and `lib32-zlib` from `[multilib]` on Arch Linux.

Comment: Pretty sure ia32-libs no longer exists, in case you want to update this